# Reading data from LONG data column in oracle gives Replacement Characters ���

Tags: oracle, toad, clob

I am trying to read data from a LONG column in Oracle which is storing an Image file. When doing so I am getting following : 
IL   39  321 30580� 3� 10 0 59��
����\0\u0010JFIF\0\u0001\u0001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0��\0C\0\b\u0006\u0006\

I think the question marks are not allowing me to decode the string.
What is the meaning of these �� ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should not use `LONG` data type at all. It is [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00201) for ages.

Apart from that, data type `LONG` is used for **text** data, i.e. like `VARCAHR2` or `CLOB`. You cannot use it for binary data like images.

**Update based on comment**

Try this function to convert LONG to BLOB - Good luck!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ConvertLONG(InChar IN LONG) RETURN BLOB IS

    dest_lob BLOB;  
    lang_context INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
    dest_offset INTEGER := 1;
    src_offset INTEGER := 1;
    read_offset INTEGER := 1;
    warning INTEGER;

BEGIN

    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(dest_lob, TRUE);
    DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB(dest_lob, TO_LOB(InChar), DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, dest_offset, src_offset, DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID, lang_context, warning);
    RETURN dest_lob;

END;
```

Comment: In my opinion it might be possible to store images in LONG because we can convert an image to a base64 encoding and then store it there isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but then your string would be pure ASCII (even much less) and never show any replacement characters or space. The main purpose of base64 encoding is to store arbitrary binary data as pure text. Obviously this is not the case for your data.

Comment: Yes that's true. But in my case, I am trying to convert the data in LONG column to Image.
The oracle database is very old. The fact is that the image is stored in a LONG column here. If only the characters present there were not garbled like �� ���� this then , I could have converted them to a valid Base64 and then to an image. 
Do you have any idea why the characters are showing up as �� ���� ?

Comment: In fact this data is not encoded as base64 - take it! Maybe the application stored binary data as text. What is the character set of the database?

Comment: The NLS_character set is US7ASCII

Comment: Ok, then if **by chance** you client `NLS_LANG` value was set to `?_?.US7ASCII` when data was inserted, it is possible to store binary data as text, because US7ASCII permits any byte value and data is not converted from client to server. In this case it might be possible to convert this data into a BLOB. See my update.

Comment: Yes. This Code helped me get the image. I had to convert the LONG column to LOB and then convert LOB column to BLOB. I exported this BLOB to a file and noticed that it contained no Garbled characters like � . I changed the extension of the exported file to .png and the image opened.

However the in the code you have given me I kept getting error on this line 

DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB(dest_lob, TO_LOB(InChar), DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, dest_offset, src_offset, DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID, lang_context, warning);

 error : 
[Error] PLS-00201 (13: 38): PLS-00201: identifier 'TO_LOB' must be declared

Comment: Strange, because [TO_LOB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions185.htm) is a simple function. Try to use a intermediate variable.

Comment: Hi there we recently went a Character set conversion where our database character set was changed from US7ASCII to AL32UTF8. After this, the function no longer worked and the BLOB data started giving our garbled characters. Do you have any idea why this is so ?

Comment: Unlike `US7ASCII` character set `AL32UTF8` **does not** permit any byte value, perhaps you destroyed your data by the conversion. I really wonder why your first action was not to convert your data to proper format, i.e. BLOB.

Comment: No. The data isn't destroyed. I can still view the replacement characters there. My first action couldn't be converting to BLOB because there is no function in Oracle to convert a LONG column to BLOB directly. I used TO_LOB to convert it to LOB first and then used your function to convert that LOB to BLOB. This worked perfectly when the character set was US7ASCII. Do you have any other idea ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of function DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB? Is is fairly obvious where you set the character set.

Comment: Yes I have. I have tried keeping every character set available but still the characters I got were still garbled. I looped through all the character set and viewed the results. 
 BEGIN
  FOR item IN (
    SELECT NLS_CHARSET_ID(a.VALUE) val  FROM V$NLS_VALID_VALUES a WHERE parameter = 'CHARACTERSET'  and ISDEPRECATED='FALSE'
  )
  LOOP
    
  END LOOP;
END;

Comment: I assume then your data is destroyed. You should have converted it into BLOB before character set change

Comment: No no. The data is still intact. The application is Finacle and it still displays the image fine. However I am trying to create my own API that can read the image directly from the database.

Comment: Function [CONVERT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions041.htm#SQLRF00620) may help you

Comment: Which character set should I convert it into ? I have tried few of them but all I get is some Chinese characters after conversion ? Do I need to convert it to blob after that ?

Comment: Of course. Again ´LONG´ and ´CLOB´ data are **not** intended to store any binary image data. Cross your fingers that your 3rd party application is working with LONG and do not touch it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171504/discussion-between-raxak-and-wernfried-domscheit).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should avoid using LONG data type columns and switch to BLOB (or CLOB, depending on what you plan to store in there). In your case, as that column contains images, that would be a BLOB.

You can't expect a SQL SELECT statement to return an image "as is" (i.e. to actually see that image on the screen) - all you get is that heap of junk characters. That's expected, it is a binary file, after all.

As you use TOAD, go to Schema Browser, open that table, view its data, right-click column that stores images and choose "Export Blobs (Longs, Raws ...)" from the menu. Follow instructions and export images into some folder on a disk.

Otherwise, you'd have to create an application (for example, using Apex) which is capable of displaying/downloading images.

If that's not what you are trying to do (as you mentioned that you'd want to "decode" a string), could you explain it?

Comment: By decode I mean, I was trying to convert the strings present in the LONG column to a base64 format and then trying to convert that base64 string to an image.
For example, this website allows converting base64 to image. 
https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

But in order to do so, the strings present in the LONG column has to be garble free. I am getting characters like �� ���� which I think is the main reason why my conversion to base64 is not resulting in a valid image.